# Check that a function raises a warning with nose tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, warnings, nose

I'm writing unit tests using [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.2/), and I'd like to check whether a function raises a warning (the function uses `warnings.warn`). Is this something that can easily be done?

Comment: `import warnings; import nose` and then `with nose.tools.assert_warns(DeprecationWarning): warnings.warn(DeprecationWarning)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def your_code():
    # ...
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
    # ...

def your_test():
    with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
        your_code()
        assert len(w) > 1
```

Instead of just checking the lenght, you can check it in-depth, of course:

`assert str(w.args[0]) == "deprecated"`

In python 2.7 or later, you can do this with the last check as:

`assert str(w[0].message[0]) == "deprecated"`

Comment: shouldn't the test be `len(w) > 0`, we just want to check if the `warnings.WarningMessage` list is empty. Or, following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) just test for empty sequences being false

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two ways of doing this. You can catch the warning in the `list` of `warnings.WarningMessage`s in test or use `mock` to `patch` the imported `warnings` in your module.

I think the `patch` version is more general.

raise_warning.py:

```
import warnings

def should_warn():
    warnings.warn('message', RuntimeWarning)
    print('didn\'t I warn you?')
```

raise_warning_tests.py:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch
import raise_warning

class TestWarnings(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('raise_warning.warnings.warn')
    def test_patched(self, mock_warnings):
        """test with patched warnings"""
        raise_warning.should_warn()
        self.assertTrue(mock_warnings.called)

    def test_that_catches_warning(self):
        """test by catching warning"""
        with raise_warning.warnings.catch_warnings(True) as wrn:
            raise_warning.should_warn()
            # per-PEP8 check for empty sequences by their Truthiness 
            self.assertTrue(wrn)
```