# Can I use nose to check that a function raises a warning, but also keep that warning message from printing on the terminal?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I want to write a nose unit test that confirms that a function issues an expected warning. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587407/check-that-a-function-raises-a-warning-with-nose-tests) shows how.

However, I would also like to not see the warning's message in the terminal window from which I'm running nosetests. (It clutters up nosetests' output.)

Is there a way to nose-test to see if a function issues a warning, without having the warning text show up?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587407/check-that-a-function-raises-a-warning-with-nose-tests/32089134#32089134

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using the https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock module's `patch` decorator, to fake the `warnings.warn` function. You can then verify that the call was made, without it actually being called.

Something like this (untested):

```
@mock.patch('yourmodule.warnings')
def your_test(self, mock_warnings):
    your_code()
    mock_warnings.warn.assert_called_with("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
```